# Override optional inherited nested properties in interfaces

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface, nested

I have the following interface:

```
export interface InterfaceA {
    propA?: any;
}

export interface MyBaseInterface extends InterfaceA {
    propA?: {
        nestedPropA?: {
            nestedNestedPropA: string;
            nestedNestedPropB: string;
        };
    };
};
```

Then I want to extend MyBaseInterface and inherit all my props but adding more, like it would result as follows

```
export interface MyNewInterface {
    propA?: {
        nestedPropA?: {
            nestedNestedPropA: string;
            nestedNestedPropB: string;
            nestedNestedPropC: string;
        };
    };
};
```

So I tried a few examples based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636756/typescript-interface-extending-another-interface-with-nested-properties) such as:

```
export interface MyNewInterface extends MyBaseInterface {
    propA?: MyBaseInterface['propA'] & {
        nestedPropA?: MyBaseInterface['propA']['nestedPropA'] & {
            nestedNestedPropC: string;
        };
    };
};
```

But it will say "MyBaseInterface does not have nestedPropA" (Since it is optional). If I make my props not optional, it won't override it. And finally if I make it `extends Required<>` it will force me further to implement props that I don't want to.

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have reached the natural borders of interface inheritance. Afaik [Lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) cannot express this optional constraint and you also cannot use Conditional types for interfaces.

Type aliases offer much more flexibility in terms of type definition and composition of optional properties:

```
type A = {
  // your base properties
};

type B = A & {
  propA?: {
    nestedPropA?: {
      nestedNestedPropA: string;
      nestedNestedPropB: string;
    };
  };
}

type C = B & {
  propA?: {
    nestedPropA?: {
      nestedNestedPropC: string;
    };
  };
}
```

Note: You cannot define `propA?: any;` in A, as `propA` type would be widened to `any` when creating intersection types and you would loose the strong typing. You can simply prove that by:

```
type T1 = any
type T2 = string
type T3 = T1 & T2 // type T3 = any ; any wins
```

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oHpNQCYHsIBnKAO32CgHd8AnAa2oEtgALKAQ1JABooiI0AEYVg+ALZoM2KGFr4wMAPwAuTtwDcKAL5aUoSFABCCWFABkyKXIXK1qDGWLAIuAArzFqq4-SlnrgByAe6eMGpEwLRMpADmWr5OkUEhHgpGEVEx8VLoulL52ij64NAAwqYmlg6yYd41fql19rkY-sm4wR1pYGWZ0XEJGPl5WkUouBAAxgA2HLTQU-ikkVBTahXFUwB0NooWljt7MNvtLqG2B2u7YadNtncdXec9ZcUyAFYArqtitfgAN2gbA4lBA+C+ay45EokwAZjFoMc1FwQFAYlADNAYCVDAAVACMplRuOgeIATKZIgNYqSoHiAMymQkWenkoA) with above example.